# What are range and domain of Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

What are range and domain of Hamiltonian? Hamiltonian is function so it should have ones. What are they?

Answer (score 7):

Hamiltonian is not a function, but an *operator* (a function in a broader sense, if you'd like):
$${\hat {H}}=-{\frac {\hbar ^2}{2m}}\nabla ^2+V(\bar{r},t)$$
It is applied to some function (our supposed $\psi$) and yields some other function. So its domain is the **set of all doubly differentiable functions** on our underlying space (the space itself can be 1D, 3D, or whatever else, depending on the nature of the problem), and the range is even broader than that, because the derivatives (or $V$, for that matter) do not have to be differentiable.

Comment: Many more requirements for the domain may be needed in some problems.
Almost all problems in molecular quantum chemistry would ask for [square integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-integrable_function) of the wave function, for instance.

Comment: That's another story altogether. Sure, a $\psi$ function requires that to be physically meaningful, but who said we can't apply our operator to ***any*** doubly differentiable function, even if it is not good as $\psi$?

Comment: Thanks. I am asking because it is often refered as a function of system state which represents system full energy which is scalar value. Or in this case it is just constant function defined on underlying space?

Comment: As you feed various functions into $\hat H$, you notice that some of them have a peculiar property: the resulting functions are proportional to the input functions, as in $\hat H\psi=E\psi$ (that's Schrodinger's equation, BTW). These are called _eigenfunctions_ of the system, and E denotes energy. See, it is a scalar value indeed, and it doesn't belong to the range of $\hat H$.